# HttpClient and HttpsURLConnection returning different certificates when using SSL

Tags: android, ssl, https

I'm using [modulus.io](https://modulus.io/) to host my app. They allow SSL piggybacking on their wildcard *.onmoulus.net certificate, and also the use your own certificates specific to your custom domain. I've been using their certificate and connecting to https://myapp.onmodulus.net using an AndroidHttpClient instance which has worked fine, but running into some problems trying to use ssl on my own custom domain name.

I've purchased and installed a certificate from thawte for my domain, and when I connect using a browser, everything goes fine. I see the little lock icon and when I inspect the certificate that's being used its my thawte certificate, not the *.onmodulus.net certificate. Before installing my own certificate it showed the "this connection is not trusted" warning and I could see the *.onmodulus.net certificate was being used.

However, when I try to connect in my android app I have less success. When opening a url and managing the httpsURLConnection like so:

```
URL myURL = new URL("https://www.myapp.com");
HttpsURLConnection myConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) myURL.openConnection();
try {
  System.out.println("Response Code : " + myConnection.getResponseCode());

  Certificate[] certs = myConnection.getServerCertificates();
  for(Certificate cert : certs){
    System.out.println("Cert Details: " + cert.toString());
  }
```

everyting goes fine, the site responds correctly and it shows that my thawte certificate, and only my thawte certificate is being used. The *.onmodulus.net certificate doesn't show up at all. However when I try to connect using DefaultHttpClient like this:

```
DefaultHttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet("https://www.myapp.com");
HttpResponse rawResponse = myClient.execute(getRequest);
```

I get a:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <www.myapp.com> != <*.onmodulus.net> OR <*.onmodulus.net> OR <onmodulus.net>
```

I'm not exactly sure how to inspect the certificates more closely but now it seems to be using the wildcard *.onmodulus.net certificate instead of my thawte certificate and I don't really understand why. I've already written my app using HttpClient instances so really would prefer to be able to connect that way instead of using something like the first solution if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modulus custom-domain SSL requires [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) support. It looks like only the HttpsURLConnection object supports connecting with SNI, based on these [docs](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html). What's happening is the DefaultHTTPClient is connecting, but since it's not providing a server name, Modulus defaults back to the *.onmodulus.net wildcard cert.

Disclaimer: I work for Modulus.

Comment: You can use SNI with HttpClient, too: http://blog.dev001.net/post/67082904181/android-using-sni-with-apache-httpclient-library